# How to send emails through Ruby on rails in linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to include a new module to my project where i can send some mails to my client.I don know how to include this emailing module . i searched in net but most of them have told to edit some SMTP.Where can i find this in linux.I am really confused about this.Plz guide me out.I need it urgently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup a mail server like [Exim4](http://www.exim.org/) on your server. Rails should be able to connect to it without any configuration.

The Rails Guides site has a great tutorial on [how to send mail](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) from your application.